# Can it be shown that numbers of a certain form produce primes more often than expected?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization, mersenne-numbers

I am trying to figure out a way to measure if numbers of a given form are prime more often than expected. This would allow some way to quantify how useful certain forms are at producing large primes. I am interested in the answer to this question generally however specifically, I am looking at generalizing Mersenne Numbers with the following particular forms where the $p_i$ are distinct odd primes:

Order 1: $$2^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}-1$$
Order 2: $$p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}-(p_1+p_2)$$
Order 3: $$2^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}p_3^{k_3}p_4^{k_4}-(p_3p_4+p_2p_4+p_2p_3)$$
Order 4: $$p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}p_3^{k_3}p_4^{k_4}-(p_2p_3p_4+p_1p_3p_4+p_1p_2p_4+p_1p_2p_3)$$
etc...

It is clear that numbers produced by this method will not be divisible by the $p_i$, but it seems to produce large primes more often than what one might intuitively "expect". For example when $p_1=3$, $p_2=5$, and $1\leq k_i\leq10$, 40% of the 100 numbers produced are prime. If we use $1/ln(x)$ as a baseline probability we would only expect about 8.4% of the 100 numbers produced to be prime. Even if we inflate $1/ln(x)$ by $5/15$ (the ratio of numbers we expect not to be divisible by 2,3 or 5) we get 25.3%.

Is there a reason why numbers of this form seem to be prime more often than expected and is this an appropriate way to measure how well a certain form and/or sets of $p_i$ are at producing primes? What might be a better way that takes into account the numbers produced are not completely random?

`? a=3;b=5;for(i=1,10, for(j=1,10, y=a+b; x=a^i*b^j-y; if(isprime(x),print(a,"^",i,"*",b,"^",j,"-",y,"=",x)) ))
3^1*5^1-8=7
3^1*5^2-8=67
3^1*5^3-8=367
3^1*5^4-8=1867
3^1*5^6-8=46867
3^1*5^8-8=1171867
3^1*5^9-8=5859367
3^2*5^1-8=37
3^2*5^3-8=1117
3^2*5^6-8=140617
3^2*5^7-8=703117
3^2*5^10-8=87890617
3^3*5^1-8=127
3^3*5^8-8=10546867
3^4*5^1-8=397
3^4*5^2-8=2017
3^4*5^6-8=1265617
3^5*5^2-8=6067
3^5*5^3-8=30367
3^5*5^8-8=94921867
3^5*5^10-8=2373046867
3^6*5^1-8=3637
3^6*5^2-8=18217
3^6*5^5-8=2278117
3^6*5^10-8=7119140617
3^7*5^2-8=54667
3^7*5^3-8=273367
3^7*5^9-8=4271484367
3^8*5^1-8=32797
3^8*5^3-8=820117
3^8*5^5-8=20503117
3^8*5^7-8=512578117
3^9*5^1-8=98407
3^9*5^2-8=492067
3^9*5^5-8=61509367
3^10*5^1-8=295237
3^10*5^2-8=1476217
3^10*5^3-8=7381117
3^10*5^8-8=23066015617
3^10*5^9-8=115330078117`

The largest prime I have found of this form without trying too hard is 500 digits:

`3 ^ 416 * 5 ^ 430 - 8 = 
10953270873453764072182016869048685865577572728474313282647298539406621226912167384457445350880070306851250032787990008339739616770392432157060556127211791099388499068153551674197920688130962853911761257267410993254028133918782946515160568303628832641933293339172177016328514094886268133058911807159869882299664338308814657437703714727309661480035874442493113008884698464990244699917853921340830065109775134806963517063427392973118461162609561117570360482009229896593893727185786701738834381103515617`

Comment: It's hard to imagine (in a vacuum) what frequency of prime numbers is "expected" when you begin by excluding some significant fraction of all integers before you search the remaining ones for primes.

Comment: @KeithBackman Yes, this is the challenge I am having, how does one define a baseline to measure a particular form against? I found this [discussion](https://primes.utm.edu/mersenne/heuristic.html) helpful, but not sure if measuring against $1/ln(x)$ is always an appropriate baseline, even in the case discussed.

Comment: @Goldbug In some special cases, we know that we cannot have a prime because there are forced factors (small prime factors or algebraic factors) , but if no such restriction prevents the expression to produce infinite many primes, we can barely predict how many primes will appear. Usually, we won't be even able to decide whether infinite many primes will appear. With one variable, the only non-trivial case that has been solved is covered by Dirichlet's theorem. Even if it comes to something like $n^2+1$ or $2^n-1$, we will need brute force calculations. (to be continued)

Comment: (continued) If we can rule out small prime factors, the chance to get a prime increases, but the $1/ln(x)$-approach still apllies in this case, just somewhat modified.

Comment: order 2 won't include $p_1\equiv p_2\equiv 5\pmod 6$ any time $k_1+k_2\equiv 0\bmod 2$